# Scala: Array[Array[Int]] to Array[Int]

Tags: scala

So I have an array of array of ints, for example

`val n = Array(Array(1,2,3), Array(4,5,6), Array(7,8,9))`

But I want to convert this to get
`Array(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9)`

Is that even possible and how?
Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use the flatten method. Calling `n.flatten` will output `Array(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9)`.

Answer (score 4):

In addition to mushroom's answer:

If it is you who is producing such 2D array (as opposed to getting it from an external source), you might make use of a `.flatMap` function instead of two nested `.map`s.

Comment: Yes, and mb it will be useful, `flatten` can be written as a `flatMap(identity)`.

Answer (score 0):

The idiomatic `flatMap` / `flatten` is the way to go; yet you can implement the flattening for instance with a for comprehension as follows,

```
for (i <- n; j <- i) yield j
```